# What are these massive CPU spikes on Google Compute Engine VMs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I checked in on a couple servers this morning to monitor the state of a long-running process and noticed a massive CPU spike reported by the Google Compute Engine console:

[Graph of VM CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLR0l.png)

I looked at more of my VMs and noticed similar, single events on all of them between about 6pm CST 12/2/2016 and 6am CST 12/3/2016.

The events all seem to have been for less than a minute. I did not notice anything unusual in the logs of the few machines I logged in to. However, several of the machines had errors within running (node.js) processes that cleared up when I restarted the processes.

I currently suspect that something was performed on Google's side and I may have nothing to worry about, but it's definitely not something I've seen before.

Comment: Did you check GCE [operation logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs) to see if there was a [host maintenance event](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#infrastructure_maintenance_events) during that time ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? If so please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.